How to configure eshell prompt to correctly display working directory on remote host over TRAMP?
Running emacs -Q for emacs 29.4 (build 2, x86_64-w64-mingw32):

~/.ssh $ cd /ssh:oracle-root:/
/ssh:oracle-root:~/ $ pwd
/ssh:oracle-root:/home/opc/
/ssh:oracle-root:~/ $ /bin/pwd
/

There should be ~/ on the second line.  The pwd command (which is eshell's own pwd written in elisp) on the second line should also not report .../home/opc/ in the current working directory on the remote host but rather just /ssh:oracle-root: like below.
Running emacs -Q for emacs 27.2 (build 1, ....redhat):

~/.ssh $ cd /ssh:oracle-root:/
/ssh:oracle-root: $ pwd
/ssh:oracle-root:
/ssh:oracle-root: $ /bin/pwd
/


Jim Porter (bug-gnu-emacs) reported back:

Thanks for the report. This is an MS-Windows only issue, fixed in 33997047e891d5513c4f33ab78ad353746ed16e2 on Emacs master (so version 31).


In the meantime though, you can customize 'eshell-pwd-convert-function' to avoid this mis-conversion; the 'identity' option should work. (I'm not actually sure why this has a different default value on MS-Windows vs other paltforms, but it's been that way for a long time so I'll just about opening that can of worms for now...)

